# Disk IOPS count in GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, iops

I can't find information about ways to count disk iops in GNU/Linux for some time period. I saw iostat, but I'm not sure it is right way. Also i need tool, that can count iops for all time since system is started, but iostat doesn't do this.
I mean disk iops for whole systems and for any logical volume.

May be there are some tools to limit disk iops for logical volume or smth like that.

If it matters, I use Debian. Also I use hardware MegaRaid Raid Controller. May be it influences on smth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iostat is the right way to get IO count over time.

If you want totals since boot, you can read those from `/proc/disktats`. Description of the file format is in your kernel's `Documentation/iostats.txt` (or [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/iostats.txt)).

This information is also available per-device or per-partition in `/sys/block/${DEVICE}/stat` and `/sys/block/${DEVICE}/${DEVPART}/stat` (substitute `${DEVICE}` with your device name eg. `sda` and `${DEVPART}` with your partition name eg. `sda5`).

Comment: Thank you for diskstats and stats in /sys. This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use `cd /dev; iostat -xk 3 sd? fio?` to watch disk IO. Take a look at this sample excerpt:

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1.20    0.00    4.58    0.00    0.00   94.22

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sdg               0.00     0.00    6.67  238.00  3413.33 39774.67   353.04     0.25    1.02   0.37   9.17
sda               0.00     0.00    5.33 3570.67  2730.67 42230.50    25.15     0.44    0.12   0.07  25.20
sdc               0.00     0.00   10.33  795.00  3089.33 44510.00   118.21     0.40    0.47   0.16  12.83
sdf               0.00     0.00    6.67  254.67  3413.33 40318.67   334.68     0.24    0.93   0.35   9.07
sdh               0.00     0.00   14.33  338.00  3444.00 43286.67   265.26     0.27    0.78   0.29  10.23
sdi               0.00     0.00    8.67  906.33  4437.33 44533.17   107.04     0.36    0.40   0.15  14.17
sdb               0.00     0.00    4.67 2355.33  2389.33 44427.50    39.68     0.51    0.21   0.08  18.87
sdd               0.00     0.00    7.00  256.00  3414.67 40434.67   333.46     0.32    1.22   0.37   9.60
sde               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
fioa              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Your average IOPS for this interval is the sum of `r/s` and `w/s` and your `avgrq-sz` (average request size in sectors) gives you an idea of whether the workload is random or sequential.

Take a look at `sdg` vs. `sda` in the example above. Both are writing around 40MBps to disk but the request size is much lower for sda (random workload) resulting in a higher IOPS.

If you want to track IOPS (and other performance) for an extended period of time I strongly suggest using [nmon](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-analyze_aix/) to collect the data and generate pretty graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Does iotop do what you want ? It's maybe a little more real-time than you wanted.

else, try `iostat 5 5`